# C - Storing main() arguments in an array

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argv, argc

I am creating a multithreaded program utilizing bankers algorithm, have all of it hard coded and compiled, but I am having a problem filling the initial `available` array from user input

```
#DEFINE NUMBER_OF_RESOURCES 3

int available[NUMER_OF_RESOURCES];       //available will be length of argc i.i number of total resoruces

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

printf("AVAILABLE RESOURCE: \n [");
//Populate Available Resource Array
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    available[i-1] = argv[i];
    printf("%d ", available[i]);
}
printf("] \n\n");
}
```

When executing with:
`./a.out 10 7 5`

It prints:

```
[1604031496 1604031499 1604031501 ]
```

Comment: Elements of `argv` are strings, not numbers. Print them with `%s`, not `%d`.

Comment: What is the type of the `available` variable?

Comment: `available[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
    printf("%d ", available[i-1]);`

Comment: You are trying to print a string pointer as an integer. `argv[]` is an array of pointers. It's quite likely from the numbers you give that the first argument had a length of 2 (size of 3) and the next argument had a length of 1 (size of 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't convert strings to integers with ordinary assignment (you should have gotten a compiler warning about assigning `char*` to `int` without a cast). Call `atoi()` to parse the integers.

```
available[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
```

Comment: You might not get an error if the compiler uses 32-bit pointers, and this may be what you actually wanted to do.

Comment: @TheTromboneWilly The size of pointers doesn't matter, they're still different types. Any decent compiler should warn about automatic conversions like this.

Comment: For parsing external inputs, use `strtol` not `atoi`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `atoi` to convert a string to an `int`.
2. Make sure you don't access `available` out of bounds.

```
for (i = 1; i < argc && i < NUMER_OF_RESOURCES+1; i++)
{
    available[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
    printf("%d ", available[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `i-1`?